# Automatically creating shortcuts on any Windows computer

Tags: windows, shortcut

I'd like to create some sort of script that will create a particular shortcut on the desktop of any Windows computer. The idea is to make the script available (to students in a course) so that they can download it to their computer and run it just by clicking it (i.e. not running it at the command-line). The script will have to check for some particular folders and files, and, if they exist, create the shortcut.

I'm a Linux guy and know very little about Windows, and so I am not even sure where to start to looking. I considered into using a Python script to do this, but that apparently requires installing some Windows-specific extensions, which I don't want to insist that that users do.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in VBScript, using the [Windows Script Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692931.aspx) which should be installed and usable on nearly any recent enough copy of Windows.

You want the `CreateShortcut()` method of the [WshShell object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156590.aspx) which gets you an object representing a shortcut. You'd modify its properties and use its `Save()` method to actually create the shortcut file.

I've linked to the scripting guide at MSTN, as well as a page specific to the shell object. That should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I often work up a quick NSIS script and compile it to an EXE.  The result is a very small executable.  You can download NSIS itself at http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download.  I recommend [HM NIS Edit](http://hmne.sourceforge.net/) to start with, as it has a wizard that builds a base script for you.  Most of that wizard won't be applicable to your situation, but it is a good way to get started.  [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) also does syntax highlighting for NSIS.

Comment: InnoSetup would also work, on the same principle. And also free.